# count the number of existing tabs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using a dynamic jQuery tab widget to add/remove tabs generated programmatically.

How do I check through jQuery and count how many existing tabs are present in the widget?

I'm using this code, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#container-1 > ul').tabs('add', tabName, name);

var newTab;

if ($('#container-1 > li').size() < 0) {
    newTab = $(tabName).css('display', 'block')
} else {
    newTab = $(tabName).css('display', 'none');
}

newTab.html('<iframe src="ViewPatient.aspx?pname=' + name 
       + '" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="300"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var tabCount = $(tabContainer).tabs("length");
```

Comment: This no longer works in jQuery-ui 1.10.0. http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-length-method  See Wolfgang's solution.

Answer (score 47):

Just use the below code

```
$('#selector >ul >li').size();
```

where "#selector" is the selector you have used to create the tabs.

**UPDATE**

`size()` function doesn't exist any more, now the solution is:

```
$('#selector >ul >li').length;
```

Comment: Note, this is now the official solution recommended by jQuery-UI.

Comment: I'd say this is much more efficient and readable:
$("selector").find(".ui-tabs-nav").children().length;
where selector is the selector you have used to create the tabs..

Comment: jQuery's .size() function was [deprecated in version 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10657). Use the .length property instead: `$('#selector >ul >li').length;`

Comment: @JSmitty Absolutely right, `size()` doesn't work any more

Comment: should be current selected answer