# jQuery UI Navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Tabs where I have 3 tabs (T1,T2 and T3) displayed and have the following setup:

```
   $(function(){
      $tabs = $("#tabs_start_reg");
      $tabs.tabs();
      $tabs.show();
   });
```

I have the following queries relating to jQuery UI tabs.

Using jQuery:

1. How can I determine which tab the user has currently clicked on?
2. How can I calculate the total amount of tabs I am using, in this case 3?
3. Within the current tab that I am on, I need to branch to another page within my website that falls outside of my jQuery UI tabs and perform some tasks there and then return back.

Now, how can I first store the tab that I am currently on, branch off to another page in the same website and then be able to return back to the tab that I was originally on?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

1) [jQuery UI Tabs Get Currently Selected Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300078/jquery-ui-tabs-get-currently-selected-tab-index)

2) [count the number of existing tabs in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175380/count-the-number-of-existing-tabs-in-jquery)

3) http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tabs-remember-currently-selected-tab-after-refresh

The magic of Google :-)

Comment: Would have double up voted you (if possible) if they were 'let me google that for you' links :D

Comment: Thanks @Martin but I still require assistance with my point 3 above.

Comment: You just need to add the cookie option to your tabs method: `$('#tabID').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 7, name: "selectedTabAdminSection" });`. After this, jQuery restores your view. If you want to reset the view, delete the Cookie.